# How can I find out the version number of Flash Player in Java?

Tags: java, flash

How can I find out the version number of the Flash player installed on my system in Java?

I currently run OS X, but the solution should be OS-agnostic.

Comment: Javascript is run in the browser that displays the website. It'll read the script and evaluate it line by line. You can't do that from Java, at least not run it in the context of that website. Can you please elaborate on what you're *really* doing? Why would you need to get the version number in Java? I just think you're approaching this the wrong way.

Comment: I just need to get the version number of the flash player. I could not think of another way to do it using only java.

Comment: Well, that depends on which operating system you're on. Does the question make more sense to you now?

Comment: Im using a mac but the program should run regardless of the OS

Comment: Do you have the XY problem? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to read the plug-in's configuration/helper files. This depends on where they're stored on each OS.

### OS X

For the system-wide Flash, read the following XML file:

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player.plugin/Contents/version.plist
```

The version number is the text value of the first occurrence of `<string>` in the `<dict>` element. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>10.2.159.1</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>10.2.159.1</string>
        <key>ProjectName</key>
        <string>FlashPlayer</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Google Chrome on the other hand ships with its own version of Flash, to be found here:

```
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/21.0.1171.0/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player Plugin for Chrome.plugin/Contents/Info.plist
```

Replace `21.0.1171.0` with the newest folder you can find in there. In the `Info.plist`, look for the first `<string>` child following the `<key>` with `CFBundleShortVersionString` as its text:

```
...
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>BRPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>11.3.300.257</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>MOSS</string>
...
```

Comment: If anybody knows where to find this in Windows or Linux, go ahead.

Comment: Does this work if all they have installed is the latest version of Chrome? I know Chrome ships with Flash internally, but I don't know if it registers it in the usual places.

Comment: Ah, of course. It's buried within the application bundle. I added that to my answer.